# forgot to add prefixes

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege4

While making ontology I forgot to add any prefix and now while applying any SPARQL query prefix is used. So do I need to make ontology again?

These are active ontology prefixes

[image]

How can I execute my SPARQL query?

Comment: You can try just using ":".  I think that may work.  So something like "?s :mypredicate ?o".

Comment: You can always declare prefixes in the preamble of the SPARQL query. `PREFIX ex: <THE_NAMESPACE_HERE> SELECT * WHERE {?s ex:foo ?o}`, so why aren't you just doing this?

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser I did not know this